# Scheme language: how to escape square brackets?

Tags: escaping, scheme

I'm adding pronounsation rule to the "festival" speech engine file `/usr/share/festival/voices/russian/msu_ru_nsh_clunits/festvox/msu_ru_nsh_lexicon.scm`.

```
  (lts.ruleset
     test_ruleset
     ( )
     (
       ( [ "[" ] = к в а д р а т н а я с к о б к а о т к р ы в а е т с я )
       ( [ "]" ] = к в а д р а т н а я с к о б к а з а к р ы в а е т с я )
```

I get error when trying to use a rule:

```
LTS_Rules:: misparsed a rule
LTS_Rules:: ([
 "]"
 ]
```

I don't know scheme language but I've read some articles about common lisp and clojure.
How can I properly escape `]` in code above? There are no problems with `[` symbol.

Comment: did you try to enter it as \\]

Comment: usepia, I tried `\]`, no problems with parsing rule, but the rule match to the text fails. Also tried: `"\]"` - error parsing rule. `"\\]"` - rule doesn't match to the text.

Comment: The error "LTS_Rules:: misparsed a rule" is not from Scheme. It's from the program. You need to lookup the exact syntax for rules in festvox.